# Getting wrong charset output from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

When I want to printout the output of jQuery AJAX, which has been recived from server. It doesn't show the right charset. What I want exactly is to get `Š` instead I am getting `?`. All files `script.js` and server php `proceed.php` are saved in UTF-8 and set in UTF-8. Database is set to UTF-8 as well. I've tried most of the things.
In `.js` file for AJAX:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    url: "proceed.php", //file to procces data
    ContentType : 'charset=UTF-8', // tried here
    global: false,
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "html"
});
```

In `.php` file:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$output = utf8_decode($sql_result);
```

All possible combinations.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried all proposed method in all possible variations and by using them, I don't get any response from server. The only time I get at least soem response is with settings mentioned above - literally. Setting AJAX `dataType: "text/html"` nor `dataType: "application/html"` doesn't help.

**CODE:**
PHP

```
if(!empty($_POST['select_had'])){
$zem = $_POST['select_had'];
$vysledek = mysql_query("SELECT typ_hadanky, jazyk FROM hlavolam RIGHT JOIN hadanka ON hlavolam.id_hlavolamu=hadanka.id_hlavolamu WHERE zeme_puvodu='$zem'");
$out = "";
while ($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array($vysledek)) {
    $zaz = $zaznam['jazyk'];
    $out .= "<option>".$zaz."</option>";
}
$vys = utf8_decode($out);
echo $vys;
```

}

jQuery:

```
$("#sel_had_zem").change(function(){
var select_had = $("#sel_had_zem option:selected").text();
console.log(select_had);
$.ajax({
  data:{'select_had':select_had},
  success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $("#sel_had_jaz option").nextAll().remove();
      $("#sel_had_jaz").append(data);
  },
  error: function(){
      alert('No server response');
  }
 });

});
```

Comment: Try `contentType: 'charset=utf-8'` and do `'dataType application/html'`

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe your data: is wrong. Would need to be `data:{"select_had":"select_had"},` you only have a single quote around the key, but no quotes around the value ? @Croolman

Comment: That is not the problem

Comment: You dont have type: "POST" in your ajax jquery

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({});` sets it as default for any jQuery.ajax

Comment: Ah, I don't know J query very well but looking at other examples of what you're trying to do shows those included in the Ajax function

Comment: I apologize but I don't believe I can help you any further with my knowledge but I do believe we've steered your question in the right way of getting a working solution. May want to repost a new question with some of the core attempts made and the outcome. I think it has to do with your jquery

Comment: That's alright, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the charset in your MySQL connection and not in the MySQL query. If you're using MySQLi then you can `mysqli_set_charset()` built-in PHP function. However, if you're using PDO then you can use it like this:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8;', USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

You can find more information about the `mysqli_set_charset()` function here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp

**Note:** Please, also ensure you've added the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your `HEAD` tag.

Comment: I use classic old MySQL, can't use MySQLi queries

Comment: I believe there's also a built-in PHP function called `mysql_set_charset()` which accept two arguments. This should work. However, I'm not much confident as this function has deprecated.
`$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');`
`mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following..

`dataType: 'html'`

to

`dataType: 'application/html'`

keep

`contentType: 'charset=utf8'`

and add `<?php header('Content-Type: application/html; charset=utf8'); ?>` to the top of your pages.

For error reporting put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page as well. If any errors arise, post the code for that line, and post the error message in your OP post.

**For your error**

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/html`

In your request header, you have sent Content-Type: html which means that you'd like to interpret the response as HTML. Now if even server send you PDF files, your browser tries to understand it as HTML. That's the problem.

So need some info as to what exactly you're trying to send and what is the recieving end doing with this data?

Comment: Doesn't help. I don't get any response now at all.

Comment: are you specifying your charset within your actual html/php page like `<?php header('Content-Type: application/html; charset=utf8'); ?>` ? you can try `text/html `or `application/html` @Croolman

Comment: I do have those headers in original php file. And I've also tried to change them as proposed. No effect.

Comment: What version of PHP is your server running?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of all your code files. Go through the steps to process what you're trying to do and it should kick out some errors and line numbers. Post those line numbers that the error is coming from.

Comment: Version of PHP is 5.3.29. And the only  "error" I am getting is when I change header to `application/html` that being:
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/html`

Comment: What type of data are you trying to transfer? Input values? JSON? defined variables?

Comment: In your request header, you have sent Content-Type: html which means that you'd like to interpret the response as HTML. Now if even server send you PDF files, your browser tries to understand it as HTML. That's the problem. So need some info as to what exactly you're trying to send and what is the recieving end doing with this data?

Comment: I am send a simple string to server with jQuery.ajax. I'd use that string as part of MySQL query. The query proceeds well, the output of the query itself is right, but it seems to be failing to pass it in the right form. If I don't use the `utf8_decode` before sending it from server, I get `ĹĄ` instead `Š`

Comment: Can you post all your code. I understand what you're trying to say, but I need to visually see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the output from the PHP-page to UTF-8 and correct MIME-type:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo $sql_result;
exit;
```

This should fix the issue!

Comment: Doesn't work. It behaves funny. After reloading page, some kind of system file is automatically downloaded.

Comment: The php-manual uses `Content-Type: text/html`. I do not know if it is better or just an older version of the http protocol?

Comment: I've been using this one myself ever since